# Is the CDF really just a running total of the PMF or am I thinking about this wrong?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

When using discrete variables (like the possible outcomes of rolling 2 die {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} ) is the CDF the same as a sum of the PMF?

For instance, take my table below. This is the frequency distribution of 213 rolls for 2 die. The mean is 7.18 and stdev is 2.58 from the 213 rolls.

Excel Norm.Dist says that the PMF is .009 for rolling a 1.
However, the CDF is .008. That doesn't make sense to me. shouldn't the CDF be .009 as well since it represents all the values <= 1 which is only 1?
Same for the prob of rolling a 2. Shouldn't the CDF be  [0.009]+[0.021] (the prob of rolling a 1 or 2)

In essence, shouldn't the CDF be the running sum of the PMF values before it?

```
[Outcome]   [Frequncy]  [PMF]   [CDF]
[1]         [0]         [0.009] [0.008246202]
[2]         [6]         [0.021] [0.022233465]
[3]         [10]        [0.042] [0.052456047]
[4]         [21]        [0.072] [0.108727782]
[5]         [28]        [0.108] [0.199012947]
[6]         [26]        [0.140] [0.32384197]
[7]         [27]        [0.154] [0.472569645]
[8]         [30]        [0.147] [0.625272517]
[9]         [17]        [0.121] [0.760380856]
[10]        [23]        [0.085] [0.863394586]
[11]        [16]        [0.051] [0.93107808]
[12]        [9]         [0.027] [0.96939936]
```

Comment: Ecerythingabou about this is confusing.  How are either the PMF *or* the CDF positive for outcome 1?  I assume when you say the outcome of rolling two dice, you mean the sum of the face values. Secondly, did you say the mean was 71.8?  What is this the mean of?

Comment: You cannot be using `Norm.Dist` correctly, because you get different values for outcomes 1 and 12, 2 and 11, etc., whereas a correct use of this Normal approximation would yield identical values for all such symmetric pairs of cases.  However, even if this were done correctly, *approximating* a discrete distribution with values from a continuous one is no way to understand properties of the discrete distribution!

Comment: I updated the question. It should have read the mean is 7.18. I am not using the idea of "fair" dice. I simulated 213 rolls of 2 dice.
So for each outcome (1-12) I computed the pmf and cdf using the mean of 7.18, the stdev of 2.58 and fed it the outcome (1-12). That is what the table represents.
So though rolling a 2 should be 1/36 chance, because this was a simulation of 213 rolls, it found a that snake eyes came up 6 times. So that s what I mean by the fact that I am not using "fair dice".

Comment: @whuber Not sure that I get what you are saying about continuous data. Rolls of dice should all be discrete in nature. We can't have 1.5, or 2.5. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'I computed the pmf and cdf using the mean of 7.18, the stdev of 2.58'? The PMF is not defined this way, anyway.

Comment: @rightskewed maybe I am doing it wrong but in excel to compute the outcome of 12 in the chart above I used this 

"=NORM.DIST(12,7.18,2.58,FALSE)"
12 = outcome
7.18 = mean
2.58 = stdev
False = PMF

Comment: The sum of 2 dice is not normally distributed, nor is it a discretized normal. So your use of the normal distribution is inappropriate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal distribution model you are using is not appropriate for the sum of two dice, which has a [well-known discrete distribution](http://mathinsight.org/probability_distribution_idea) - you might want to look at [how this result is proved on Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-seventh-grade-math/cc-7th-probability-statistics/cc-7th-compound-events/v/events-and-outcomes-2), though that is a theoretical approach and it seems you are going about it in an empirical way. But even if your model were appropriate for some other scenario, what you are doing in Excel won't work.

The final "false" in your NORMDIST does indeed [stop the output being cumulative](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827371) but it means the output is a PDF not a PMF since the normal distribution is continuous. A PMF *sums* to the CDF whereas a PDF *integrates* to the CDF.

You could see this in Excel by using a finer mesh of points - set them 0.01 apart, say, rather than just looking at whole numbers - and using a numerical integration procedure. Even something simple like the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) should give you an overall integral close to one, and intermediate integrals close to your calculated CDFs. To achieve better results with minimal extra complication you might want to start further to the left than zero (four or five standard deviations to the left of your mean should be plenty for your purposes), using a better numerical integration procedure such as [Simpson's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) and setting an even finer mesh, but even the rough and ready result you'd get from the trapezoidal rule ought to be convincing.

**Excel code**

Paste special as a CSV, with the delimiter set as semi-colon, so that "Outcome" is in cell `A1` - then clone down cells `A4:D5` for a couple of thousand rows.

```
Outcome;PDF;CDF;Trapezium rule estimate
-4.00;=NORM.DIST(A2,7.18,2.58,0);=NORM.DIST(A2,7.18,2.58,1);
-3.99;=NORM.DIST(A3,7.18,2.58,0);=NORM.DIST(A3,7.18,2.58,1);
-3.98;=NORM.DIST(A4,7.18,2.58,0);=NORM.DIST(A4,7.18,2.58,1);=(0.01/2)*(B$2+B4+2*SUM(B$3:B3))
-3.97;=NORM.DIST(A5,7.18,2.58,0);=NORM.DIST(A5,7.18,2.58,1);=(0.01/2)*(B$2+B5+2*SUM(B$3:B4))
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I was somewhat following this technique (https://www.apsu.edu/sites/apsu.edu/files/wilsona/Rolling_Two_Dice_Empirical_Rule__Z-Scores.pdf) and thought that I could use a normal distribution since it looked so similar and gave probabilities that were extremely similar to what textbook probabilities are to the two dice question. I guess the fact that it showed that I had a small statistical chance of rolling a 13 should have tipped me off.